# Isolating script with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

[image]

I have loaded the entire HTML page in BeautifulSoup.Is there a way I can isolate this collection of dictionaries?

- The type (in yellow) appears only once in the page, there are no duplicates

This is the code I used to import the HTML file (cannot use urllib):from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Projects/20200710_StreetEasy_WebScraping/1.html') as f:
  contents = f.read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Searching for the a tags returns output

```
a = soup.find_all('a')
a
[<a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" href="https://cdn-assets-s3.streeteasy.com/assets/manifest-c93475b02bd2409b4a52e21af023e5d5f489f19500d234a3660fe4d35069bbac.json" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">//cdn-assets-s3.streeteasy.com/assets/manifest-c93475b02bd2409b4a52e21af023e5d5f489f19500d234a3660fe4d35069bbac.json</a>,
 <a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" href="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/5.19.0/bundle.min.js" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/5.19.0/bundle.min.js</a>,
 <a class="html-attribute-value html-resource-link" href="https://cdn-assets-s3.streeteasy.com/assets/jquery-fe1be651ec56a9cc875a437f09db5b175cc6acf4b911bed0ef265955a099db55.js" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">//cdn-assets-s3.streeteasy.com/assets/jquery-fe1be651ec56a9cc875a437f09db5b175cc6acf4b911bed0ef265955a099db55.js</a>,
...
```

Searching for the script tags returns no output

```
import re
scripts = soup.find_all("script")
scripts
[]
```

Maybe I did something wrong when importing the document?

Comment: Do you mind posting that output in markdown rather than including the png? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I just tried importing the html code but does not show up clearly, unable to set the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [string](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#id12) argument from [find_all](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#find-all) to filter the script tags containing the `@context` JSON

`scripts = soup.find_all("script", string=re.compile("@context"))`

Then loop through your `scripts` and load the JSON after removing `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]`

Comment: Tried but it does not work, I added details in the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've done something like

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

you can isolate that particular element using BeautifulSoup's `find()` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

```
script = soup.find("script", {"type" : "application/ld+json"})
```

Comment: Tried but it does not work, I added details in the question